# Detail of the excess speed

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have a problem with T-SQL and I do not know how to solve it, I would appreciate it very much if you can help me please.

Table
Date                        Id                   Speed
01-02-17:01:00       PTWE23        23
01-02-17:01:10       PTWE23        25
01-02-17:01:20       PTWE23        31
01-02-17:01:30       PTWE23        41
01-02-17:01:40       PTWE23        43
01-02-17:01:50       PTWE23        34
01-02-17:02:00       PTWE23        16
01-02-17:02:10       PTWE23        3
02-02-17:02:20       PTWE23        11
02-02-17:02:30       PTWE23        35
02-02-17:02:40       PTWE23        42
02-02-17:02:50       PTWE23        46
02-02-17:03:00       PTWE23        41
02-02-17:03:10       PTWE23        21
02-02-17:03:20       PTWE23        10
02-02-17:03:30       PTWE23        0
02-02-17:04:20       AABB01        30
02-02-17:04:30       AABB01        38
02-02-17:04:40       AABB01        45
02-02-17:04:50       AABB01        50
02-02-17:04:00       AABB01        52
02-02-17:05:10       AABB01        43
02-02-17:05:20       AABB01        41
02-02-17:05:30       AABB01        33

I need a view like this

DateFrom                 DateTo                       Id                     Over Speed (40 km/hour)
01-02-17:01:30         01-02-17:01:40         PTWE23         10 Sec
02-02-17:02:40         02-02-17:03:00         PTWE23         20 Sec
02-02-17:04:40         02-02-17:05:20          AABB01         40 Sec

Thanks
Patricio

Comment: You should be more explicit about how you define the groups.

Comment: @Gordon I think a "group" is just a contiguous group of records having a speed in excess of 40 km/h, which seems to be the speed limit.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen . . . Interesting.  That is not my interpretation (or at least not my initial interpretation).

Comment: Just look at the expected output, you will see it.  I don't think your current query would generate this because you are grouping by the date proper.  Anyway, the answer is beyond my ability :-(

Comment: Sorry i was wrong about the title
must say, make a detail of the excess speed

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what your criteria are.  For your data, you can define the groups by `id` and date.  Here is one attempt at an answer:

```
select min(date), max(date), id,
       sum(case when speed > 40 then 10 else 0 end) - 10 as overspeed
from t
group by id, cast(date as date);
```

The above produces the specified results.

However, if you are looking for *islands* of time over 40, then you can use a difference of row numbers:

```
select min(date), max(date), id, 
       datediff(second, min(date), max(date)) as num_seconds
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id order by date) as seqnum_i,
             row_number() over (partition by id, (case when speed > 40 then 1 else 2 end)
                                order by id
                               ) as seqnum_is
      from t
     ) t
where speed > 40
group by id, (seqnum_i - seqnum_is);
```